# How do I make this flex box work in safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have this snippet

```css
div.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 h250" id="Obj1"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 h250" id="Obj2"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 h550" id="Obj3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 h550" id="Obj4"></div>
</div>
```

Now the thing is that Obj1 and Obj2 must be shown on 1 row. Therefor i added the sm-6. But for some reason Obj1 and Obj2 will be shown on 2 rows in Safari. Chrome it looks fine. I checked both Safari on iOS and MacOS, both the same problem.

Did i miss something in the CCS?

Comment: are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4? (in 4 it works here)

Comment: 3. But i just tested 4, and my code has the same behaviour there

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: Actually, why are you using flexbox on this? The bootstrap classes alone have exactly the effect you are looking for (?)

Comment: What does the `h250` and `h550` classes do?

Comment: And doesn't this work in Safari https://jsfiddle.net/t719p8jv/